# How to do this multiple IF statement in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, nested

I have this table:

```
scanner name | maxwidth | maxlength
====================================
scanner A    | 50       | 100
scanner B    | 60       | 120
```

in my PHP i have:

```
$paperW = 70;
$paperL = 55;
```

how to do the mysql query so that my result will return:

```
scanner name
============
scanner B
```

*The idea is to find which scanner fits the paper size. Although the paper width is 70 and length is 55, and printer B only have max width of 60, we can always rotate the paper orientation so that the paper width becomes 55 and the length becomes 70 which will fit scanner B.*

in pseudo-code to check if a scanner fits the paper will be like this:

```
if (paperW <= maxWidth && paperL <= maxLength)
 return true
else{
 if (paperW >  maxWidth){
    if (paperW <= maxLength && paperL <= maxWidth)
       return true;
    else
       return false;
 }
 else
  return false;
}
```

I have no idea to transalte that into MySQL Query.. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Have you looked into `WHERE` statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the rectangle area in your php.

```
RectArea = width * length;
```

and use the `RectArea` in the where clause.

```
 SELECT 
     SCANNER_NAME,
     MAX_WIDTH,
     MAX_LENGTH,
     (MAX_WIDTH * MAX_LENGTH) PAGE_AREA 
 FROM Scanners
    WHERE (MAX_WIDTH * MAX_LENGTH)  >=  RectArea ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 
 "SELECT FROM scanners 
  WHERE ( maxwidth <= ".(int)$paperW." 
       && maxlength <= ".(int)$paperL)." 
  OR
        ( maxwidth <= ".(int)$paperL." 
       && maxlength <= ".(int)$paperW." )
     ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a where clause similar to:

```
WHERE (paperW <= maxWidth AND paperL <= maxLength) OR 
      (paperL <= maxWidth AND paperW <= maxLength)
```

This will get you most of the way.  Be aware that it likely to return multiple rows, so you may want to do some ordering to get the best match and add a `LIMIT 1` to return a single row.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right answer (i think xD) :

```
SELECT * FROM scanners 
WHERE 
(maxwidth >= paperW and maxlength >= paperL) #First case
or 
(maxwidth >= paperL and maxlength >= paperW) #Rotating paper
```

Saludos ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select scanner_name from your_table 
 where ('$paperW' <= maxwidth and $paperL <= maxlength ) 
  OR  ('$paperW' <= maxlength and $paperL <= maxwidth )
```

[**DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50369/1)